# connecting check box to query as a filter criteria for values

Tags: asp.net-mvc, checkbox

i am new in MS MVC and i have this problem.I try to filter data in database with some checkboxes.
I am using MS MVC. LINQ to SQL, MS SQL Express.

```
 <% using (Html.BeginForm())
      { %>
      <fieldset>
      <legend>Search filter</legend>
      <fieldset style="width:130px;height:150px;float:left;margin-left:10px">
      <legend></legend>
    <table>
  <tr><td><%= Html.CheckBox("checkbox", false)%></td><td>Solar</td></tr>
  <tr><td><%= Html.CheckBox("checkbox1", false)%></td><td>Water</td></tr>
  <tr><td><%= Html.CheckBox("checkbox2", false)%></td><td>Biomas</td></tr>
  <tr><td><%= Html.CheckBox("checkbox3", false)%></td><td>Other....</td></tr>
  </table>
  </fieldset>
```

Controller.cs

```
public ActionResult Search()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public ActionResult Search(FormCollection formValues)
        {
            string value = formValues["checkbox"];
            string value2 = formValues["checkbox1"];
            string value3 = formValues["checkbox2"];
            string value4 = formValues["checkbox3"];

            var dataContext = new powerPlantModelDataContext();

            var solar = from q in dataContext.TypeDetails
                              where q.KindName.Equals(value.ToString())
                              select q;

            if (solar != null) { ViewData["solar"] = solar.ToList(); }

            return View();
        }
```

Collect and view data in view.aspx

```
<%foreach (RenewalSourcesWeb.Models.TypeDetail solar in (List<RenewalSourcesWeb.Models.TypeDetail>) ViewData["solar"]) {%>
    <table>

    <tr><td>Value1</td><td><%=solar.Description %></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Value2</td><td><%=solar.KindName %></td></tr>

    </table>
    <%} %>
```

My problem is that check box value is i suppose true or false no checkbox and i cant make this work.
If someone have some suggestion, i will appreciate any help.Also if anyone have suggestion to solve multiple check boxes are true.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some suggestions for you:

1.) Unless you have a requirement that forces you to use MVC version 2 or 1, change from the WebForms view engine (<% syntax like this %>) to the Razor view engine (`@Syntax.LikeThis`).

2.) Use a strongly-typed ViewModel instead of `ViewData`.

```
public class SearchViewModel
{
    public bool checkbox { get; set; }
    public bool checkbox1 { get; set; }
    // ...etc
}

public ActionResult Search()
{
    return View(new SearchViewModel());
}

<tr><td>@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.checkbox)</td><td>Solar</td></tr>
<tr><td>@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.checkbox1)</td><td>Water</td></tr>

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Search(SearchViewModel model)
{
    string value = model.checkbox;
    string value2 = model.checkbox1;
    // ...etc
```

3.) When searching, submit the form using GET instead of POST. POST is when you are changing data, GET is for when you are querying data (like search).

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "Search", FormMethod.Get))
{
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer ,i get your point. But actually i am forced to use mvc 2 becauce my whole project is in older vercion without using razor engine and i dont have time to get into this new technology and rebuild the whole project.
Anyway thanks for effort.
Regards George

Comment: @user661597, you can still use my suggestions #2 and #3. Just substitute my razor syntax with webforms syntax.